# How to grep lines between two repeating patterns in a big file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, text

I tried to extrac from txt file with a constant pattern "beginPattern" and "endPattern", between them only key value in line1 and line2 are index then values for gettting extracted can be find in any line (key=value;)

```
[BEGIN_PATTERN]
    line1=abd;
    line2=ZXY;
    ...
    line43=454; 
    ...
    ...
[END_PATTERN]
[BEGIN_PATTERN]
    line1=abc;
    line2=ZXC;
    ...
    line72=847;
    ...
[END_PATTERN]
[BEGIN_PATTERN]
    line1=abe;
    line2=ZXV;
    ...
    line33=135;
    ...
[END_PATTERN]
[BEGIN_PATTERN]
    line1=abt;
    line2=ZXF;
    ...
    line54=734;
    ...
[END_PATTERN]
```

the expected result is:

```
abd,ZXY,aaa,454,ggg,ggs
abc,ZXC,mgf,847,jde,g3e
abe,ZXV,ytd,135,dfs,jhf
abt,ZXF,ytf,734,ytd,hge
```

I tried with python script and `re.match`, it only read and write in output file the value `abd,ZXY` into first beginPattern and endPattern found

```
import re

START_PATTERN = '<BEGIN'
END_PATTERN = '<BEND'

with open('DB_example.txt') as file:
    match = False
    newfile = None

    for line in file:
        if re.match(START_PATTERN, line):
            match = True
            newfile = open('my_new_file.txt', 'w')
            continue
        elif re.match(END_PATTERN, line):
            match = False
            newfile.close()
            continue
        elif match:
            #remove TAB and BreakLine
            valor=line.rstrip().replace('\t','')
            #split Key and value
            (key, val) = valor.split('=')
            if re.match('line1',key):
                match = True
                #before write into file remove ";"
                newfile.write(val.replace(';',''))
                continue
            elif re.match('line2',key):
                match:False
                newfile.write(','+val.replace(';', ''))
                continue
            elif re.match('lineXX',key):
                match:False
                newfile.write(','+val.replace(';', ''))
                continue
            elif re.match('lineYY',key):
                match:False
                newfile.write(','+val.replace(';', ''))
                continue
```

it does not continue with second, third and further Patterns. my files has at least 300k matches. 
I appreciate your help.

Comment: match:False ? Dont you get any error?

Comment: I tried with match:True too, same result.I don’t get any error.  Output file is written but only with value1 and value2 from first match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you are opening the file and after writing you are closing the file.
So after opening the file, each time newfile.write just overwrite the previous one.

If you want to add the new val to the file try to open the file only once before writing anything and after writing all the values you should close the file.

```
import re

START_PATTERN = '<BEGIN'
END_PATTERN = '<BEND'
newfile = open('my_new_file.txt', 'w')
with open('DB_example.txt') as file:
    match = False
    for line in file:
        if re.match(START_PATTERN, line):
            match = True
            continue
        elif re.match(END_PATTERN, line):
            match = False
            continue
        elif match:
            #remove TAB and BreakLine
            valor=line.rstrip().replace('\t','')
            #split Key and value
            (key, val) = valor.split('=')
            if re.match('line1',key):
                match = True
                #before write into file remove ";"
                newfile.write(val.replace(';',''))
                continue
            elif re.match('line2',key):
                match:False
                newfile.write(','+val.replace(';', ''))
                continue
            elif re.match('lineXX',key):
                match:False
                newfile.write(','+val.replace(';', ''))
                continue
            elif re.match('lineYY',key):
                match:False
                newfile.write(','+val.replace(';', ''))
                continue

newfile.close()
```